# Redirecting http to https in vps

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, vps

I have a vps set up on the domain "mysite.co.uk" and I also installed an SSL certificate. But it is shown only when using "https://mysite.co.uk".

How can I set it up so that 
*mysite.co.uk*
 would redirect to the one with "https"?

I tried adding a "**Redirect**" in the hosting service and I have the following too in my `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ewewew@gmail.com
        ServerName mysite.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
        Redirect / https://mysite.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try with following steps :

**Enable modules**

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

**Edit configurations**

Edit file : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    <path to your crt file>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   <path to your private key file>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Restart apache2**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I actually add the missing lines in my `mysite.co.uk.conf` instead of `000-default.conf` and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Okay. That's correct for your domain. If there are multiple domains in same VPS you can enable SSL for all domains just by adding to `000-default.conf`.